# Multivariable Weighted shift and subnormality

Tags: operator-theory, hilbert-spaces

I have asked [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1799214/subnormal-weighted-shift-and-first-order-derivative) in mathstackexchange but didn't get any answer. I hope, I will get my answer here.

Let $\mathbb B^m$ denote the Euclidean ball in $\mathbb C^m.$ Does there exist a Reinhardt measure $\mu$ supported on $\partial \mathbb B^m,$ the boundary of the ball, so that the Hilbert space $H^2(\mu)$, closure of all the polynomials in $m$ variables in $L^2(\mu)$, becomes a Reproducing Kernel Hilbert space with kernel $K$ having the following property $K(0,0)=1$ and  $\partial_{z_i}\bar{\partial}_{z_j}(K(z,z)|_{z=0} = \delta_{i,j}?$

I know the answer in the $m=1$ case. The usual Hardy space with Szegő kernel $S(z,w) = \frac{1}{1-z\bar w}$ serves the purpose. In fact I suspect, in this case, this is the only one. But in general, when $m > 1,$ the kernel for the Hardy space is of the form $$K(z,w)= \frac{1}{(1- \langle z, w \rangle )^m}$$ But here in this case, we have $\partial_{z_i}\bar{\partial}_{z_j}(K(z,z)|_{z=0} = m \delta_{i,j}.$ But if we consider the Kernel function $K(z,w)= \frac{1}{1-\langle z, w \rangle},$ then the problem is that it doesn't arise from any measure supported on $\partial \mathbb B^m.$ At this point I am stuck.

Any help or comment would be great.